# How can I reduce this system (differential equations below) to a space state (matrix A, B, C, D)?

Tags: control-theory, classical-mechanics, linearization

I have the system below

\begin{align}
\ddot{\varphi } &=\frac{ \tau_e -m_P.R.\ddot{\alpha}.l.\cos\alpha+m_P.R.\dot{\alpha}^2.l.\sin\alpha-C_D.\pi.R^5.\rho.\dot{\varphi}^2}{J_B.R^2}\\
\ddot{\alpha}&=\frac{\tau - m_P.R.\ddot{\varphi}.l.\cos\alpha-m_p.g.l.\sin\alpha}{m_P.l^2}
\end{align}

when I tried linearized that system I always get something with the form:

$\dot{x}=Ax+Bu+\text{constants}$

where $x$ is the state variables. $x=[\alpha, \varphi, \dot{\alpha}, \dot{\varphi}]$

I'm kind stuck to linearize the system to get the space state.
I'm trying to linearize at $\alpha=\pi/4,\dot{\alpha}=0,\varphi=0,\dot{\varphi}=\bar{\dot{\varphi}}, \ddot{\varphi}=0$ using Taylor expansion.
$\bar{\dot{\varphi}}$ is the mean angular velocity.

I need something in the form $\dot{x}=Ax+Bu$ without the constants.

Comment: How can you linearize at $\dot{\varphi}=\bar{\dot{\varphi}}$, while you also use $\varphi=0$? Or is $\bar{\dot{\varphi}}=0$? And what are you using as the linearization point of $\tau_e$ and $\tau$?

Comment: To avoid the constants, in case of set-point control, the linearization should be applied over a steady state equilibrium set of variables.

Comment: $\tau$ and $\tau _e$ are the control variables. $\tau=m_p.l.sin\alpha$

Comment: Are you sure the equations are correct? AFAIS you have nowhere $\varphi$, so you could just remove it from the state vector and get a third order system. Or do you want to control $\varphi$ itself? You should probably also specify the output of your system.